# Título de Tooltip personalizado no funciona cuando hace 'hover' en '<img>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estoy desarrollando un "**plugin tooltip**" gratuito en `jQuery` que subiré a `GitHub` para cualquier persona que quiera pueda usarlo, y todo estaba funcionando muy bien.

**El problema** es que, cuando traté de probar la "información sobre un elemento (tooltip)" en una imagen usando la etiqueta `<img>`, no funciona.

**Incluso traté de usar** "`clientWidth`", porque todo el mundo dice que el tamaño de una imagen se define después de que la página se haya cargado completamente, de lo contrario se devolverá `0`.

```
$('.elementoImg').width($(this)[0].clientWidth);
// No funciona
```

**Pero el "elemento tooltip"** se crea en el DOM, simplemente no funciona o no se muestra en la pantalla cuando hago `hover`.

Aquí está el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
$(".infoTie").mousemove(function ( event ) {

    var iTiePageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
    var $infotieData = $(".infoTie-data");

    //set the actuall width
    var $iTie_Pos_top = event.pageY;
    var $iTie_Pos_left = event.pageX - 60;
    var $iTie_Data_width = $("body").width() - $infotieData.width();
    var $dataArrow = $(".infoTie-data-arrow");

    //check if left not minus
    if (event.pageY > 60) {
        $iTie_Pos_top = $iTie_Pos_top - 55;
        jQuery(this).find($dataArrow).addClass("infoTie-data-arrow-top infotie-dr-top").removeClass("infoTie-data-arrow");
    } else {
     $iTie_Pos_top = $iTie_Pos_top + 15;
        jQuery(this).find(".infoTie-data-arrow-top").addClass("infoTie-data-arrow").removeClass("infoTie-data-arrow-top infotie-dr-top");
    }
    
    if ($iTie_Pos_left < 0) {
        $iTie_Pos_left = 10;
        jQuery(this).find($dataArrow).addClass("infotie-dr-left");
    } else if ($iTie_Pos_left > $iTie_Data_width) {
        $iTie_Pos_left = $iTie_Data_width - 25;
        jQuery(this).find($dataArrow).addClass("infotie-dr-right");
    } else {
     //fix for now, too lazy and too late for this shit
     $infotieData.css("margin-left", "-25px");
    }

    $infotieData.css("top", $iTie_Pos_top +  "px");
    $infotieData.css("left", $iTie_Pos_left + "px");
});


$(".infoTie").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append("<div class='infoTie-data'>" + $(this).attr("data-infoTie") + "<div class='infoTie-data-arrow'></div></div>");
  },
  function () {
    $(".infoTie-data").remove();
  }
);
```

```css
.infoTie {display:inline-block;}
.bgimg{
    background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1);
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

.infoTie-data {
    width : auto;
    height : auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:7px 10px;
    border-radius : 3px;
    background-color : #1a1a1a;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.infoTie:hover .infoTie-data {
    opacity:1;
}
.infoTie-data-arrow {
    content: "";
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #1a1a1a;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.infoTie-data-arrow-top {
    content: "";
    border-top: 8px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.infotie-dr-top {
    margin-left:-10px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
}
.infotie-dr-left {
    top: -8px;
    left: initial;
    margin-left:initial;
}
.infotie-dr-right {
    top: -8px;
    left: initial;
    right: 10px;
    margin-left:initial;
}
/* If tooltip's on top */
.infoTie-data-arrow-top.infotie-dr-top.infotie-dr-left {
    top: initial;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: initial;
    margin-left:initial;
}
.infoTie-data-arrow-top.infotie-dr-top.infotie-dr-right {
        top: initial;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: initial;
    right: 10px;
    margin-left:initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="infoTie" data-infoTie="Mouse encima del texto.">Pasar el mouse encima de este texto</div>

<h3>En la etiqueta "img" con la pequeña imagen abajo, no pasa nada.......</h3>
<img class="midImage infoTie" data-infoTie="Click drag to draw the area" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" width="100" height="50"/>

<h3>El siguiente con la imagen de fondo funciona bien</h3>
<div class="bgimg infoTie" data-infoTie="Esta es una imagen background de Béisbol"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es el tamaño de la imagen, las dimensiones del elemento las tomas en el evento `mousemove` así que la imagen debería estar cargada cuando el evento se dispare.

El problema es que estás intentando añadir el tooltip **dentro de la imagen** y los elementos `img` no admiten hijos `(childNodes)`, al igual que otros elementos como los `input` o los `link`. Estos elementos no son *per se* contenedores, es por eso que se construyen con un `tag` que se auto-cierra (por ejemplo: `<elemento/>`) ya que no albergan a otros elementos dentro de sí, cosa que sí hacen los elementos que se construyen con un `tag` inicial que abre y uno final que cierra (por ejemplo: `<elemento>...</elemento>`).

Para resolver tu problema, como siempre habrá solamente un tooltip en el `DOM`, añádelo a un elemento que sea padre de todos tus elementos y todo te irá bien. Por ejemplo, el `body`:

```
$(".infoTie").hover(
    function () {
        $("body").append("<div class='infoTie-data'>" + $(this).attr("data-infoTie") + "<div class='infoTie-data-arrow'></div></div>");
    },
    ...
```

Aquí te dejo un `snippet` funcional que usa el `body` como contenedor de los tooltips:

```js
$(".infoTie").mousemove(function(event) {

  var iTiePageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
  var $infotieData = $(".infoTie-data");

  //set the actuall width
  var $iTie_Pos_top = event.pageY + 10;
  var $iTie_Pos_left = event.pageX - $infotieData.outerWidth() / 2;
  var $dataArrow = $(this).find(".infoTie-data-arrow");

  //check if left not minus
  if (event.pageY > 60) {
    $dataArrow.addClass("infoTie-data-arrow-top infotie-dr-top").removeClass("infoTie-data-arrow");
  } else {
    $dataArrow.addClass("infoTie-data-arrow").removeClass("infoTie-data-arrow-top infotie-dr-top");
  }

  if ($iTie_Pos_left < 0) {
    $dataArrow.addClass("infotie-dr-left");
  } else {
    $dataArrow.addClass("infotie-dr-right");
  }

  $infotieData.css("top", $iTie_Pos_top + "px");
  $infotieData.css("left", $iTie_Pos_left + "px");
});

$(".infoTie").hover(
  function() {
    $("body").append("<div class='infoTie-data'>" + $(this).attr("data-infoTie") + "<div class='infoTie-data-arrow'></div></div>");
  },
  function() {
    $(".infoTie-data").remove();
  }
);
```

```css
.infoTie {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bgimg {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.infoTie-data {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.infoTie:hover .infoTie-data {
  opacity: 1;
}

.infoTie-data-arrow {
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #1a1a1a;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.infoTie-data-arrow-top {
  content: "";
  border-top: 8px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.infotie-dr-top {
  margin-left: -10px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
}

.infotie-dr-left {
  top: -8px;
  left: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
}

.infotie-dr-right {
  top: -8px;
  left: initial;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: initial;
}


/* If tooltip's on top */

.infoTie-data-arrow-top.infotie-dr-top.infotie-dr-left {
  top: initial;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
}

.infoTie-data-arrow-top.infotie-dr-top.infotie-dr-right {
  top: initial;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: initial;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="infoTie" data-infoTie="Mouse encima del texto.">Pasar el mouse encima de este texto</div>

<h3>En la etiqueta "img" con la pequeña imagen abajo, ahora funciona porque el tooltip está añadido al body</h3>
<img class="midImage infoTie" data-infoTie="Click drag to draw the area" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" width="100" height="50" />

<h3>El siguiente con la imagen de fondo funciona bien</h3>
<div class="bgimg infoTie" data-infoTie="Esta es una imagen background de Béisbol"></div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, es verdad! A veces estamos tan centrados en otros aspectos del proyecto, que no vemos estas pequeñas cosas. Muchas gracias hermano :D

Comment: De nada amigo. Un saludo ;)